# rails css: website not responsive on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

My website looks great on desktop but I'm having trouble making it responsive on mobile devices (it's just a zoomed out version of the desktop website, except for the jumbotron that is actually completely zoomed in and blurry...).

The website is just one homepage with a jumbotron that takes up the entire screen size and then multiple sections one after the other that 'wrap' over the jumbotron when scrolling down. This effect looks great on desktop so I'd like to keep it, but I believe this may be why it's completely unresponsive on smaller devices.

My jumbotron:

```
<div class="container-fluid jumbo">
  <div class="jumbo-text text-center">
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <div class="btn btn-primary mt-3"><a href="tel:06 00 00 00 00" class="text-white"><i class="fa fa-phone-alt mr-2"></i> 06 00 00 00 00</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My homepage (the content class allows me to do the section wrap over jumbotron effect):

```
<%= render 'jumbotron' %>

<div class="content">
  <%= render 'therapy' %>
  <%= render 'consult' %>
  <%= render 'modalities' %>
  <%= render 'method' %>
  <%= render 'background' %>
  <%= render 'contact' %>
  <%= render 'map' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer'%>
</div>
```

My main.css (I believe this might be where the problem is, with all of the z-index, and fixed jumbotron?):

```
/* HOMEPAGE */

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-section {
  padding-top: 7rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

/* JUMBOTRON */

.jumbo {
  background-image: url("L1000286.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
}

.jumbo-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%!important;
  z-index: 10;
  color: rgb(236, 234, 234);
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%!important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 50px
}
```

Example of a section (they're essentially always the same layout):

```
<section class="bg-primary text-white custom-section" id="consult">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Title</h3><br>

    <p>Some random text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

My main.js:

```
function dynamicNavbar() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var height = $(window).height() - $(".navbar").height();
    
        if (scroll >= height) {
            $(".navbar").addClass("bg-pink");
        } else {
          $(".navbar").removeClass("bg-pink");
        }
    });   
  });
};

function softScroll() {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "a.scrollLink" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top }, 500);
    });
  });

}

softScroll();
dynamicNavbar();
```

My application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "layouts/navbar" %>
    <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I could do to make my website friendly?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  I didn't see any mobile breakpoint style updates in your stylesheet, it looks like you are using bootstrap, but you are not setting any breakpoints in the HTML entities either, what is suppose to change? Can you elaborate a little bit on what you expect it to look like exactly?

Comment: Right now the mobile version works fine, but it is just a zoomed out version of the desktop website, so the text/buttons/navbar and everything else is very small which isn't practical. I'm still very new at this obviously, but in previous websites I made, I've never had to use any CSS breakpoints to make it responsive. Using bootstrap was enough. The only thing I did different this time is the wrap over jumbotron effect, which makes me think it prevents my sections from being responsive. I just can't figure out why and how to fix it without messing up the wrap over jumbotron effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing a viewport tag in your layout. This is from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) if that's what you're using.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    ...
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much